# Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" and "pk-gtk-module" while opening mysql-workbench-community

Tags: mysql-workbench

The missing modules cause the workbench to show squares in the welcome screen as if it cannot encode the text. However, the text inside a local instance when I log in is normal, except for the panel on the left.

[image: users and privileges screen]

[image: workbench welcome screen]

I have tried many solutions but nothing has worked. For example,
`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`, or `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*` .

I have **Ubuntu 22.04.2** installed, and I have the snap version of MySQL-workbench-community.